# Google app engine deploy of django application, how to make python manage.py migrate using cloud_sql_prox?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to deploy a django application in app engine flexible.

I'm having trouble performing python manage.py migrate from my application, using cloud_sql_prox
I performed the following steps

Initialize the Cloud SQL instance
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances = "[cei-bd]" = tcp: 5432
More when executing python manage.py migrate
You have this message

Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/teste-2-195911:us-east1:teste-bd/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

**Settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'teste',
    'USER': 'teste-prod',
    'PASSWORD': 'osgeniteste',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'HOST': '/cloudsql/teste-2-195911:us-east1:teste-bd',
}}
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT osgeni.wsgi

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: teste-2-195911:us-east1:teste-bd

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Comment: Are you testing this locally?  And what’s your operating system?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint